# How can I use JPaginator without database?

Tags: joomla-3.x, pagination

The question is really simple: Can I use the standard paginator to paginate data that doesn't come from the main database? For example, to paginate an array, a file, or data fetched without using JDatabase?

If it's possible, how can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

I think it is posible. althoug I have not done if before.

The pagination uses as parameters the total number of records that in your case is the array count, the limitstart (index where to start), and the page size.

This is an example in one of my models to get the pagination object

```
function getPagination()
{

    if (empty($this->_pagination)) {
        jimport('joomla.html.pagination');
            $this->_pagination = new JPagination($this->getTotal(), $this->getState('limitstart'),$this->getState('limit') );
        }
    return $this->_pagination;
}
```

Sustitute $this->getTotal() for array count and so on.

Also, on the function to retrieve the data you should have and equivalent funciotn to this

```
$rows = $this->_getList($query, $this->getState('limitstart'), $this->getState('limit'));
```

to get the information from your structure

Comment: I don't understand the last part: Do you mean that in my `getItems()` functions I should have something like the `$rows = $this->_getList()` call? As far as I understand, returning a subarray of `limit` elements starting on `limitstart` will be enough, isn't it?

Comment: I just put he way we do with the database, but you are right. You should have a way to return the subarray using limistart and limit